# How do I set a PlotStyle when plotting a Table of functions?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I want to plot several functions each with its own color. A MWE is as follows :

```
Plot[{2 x, 3 x}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

which works fine. Now, as I have more than just a few functions, I'd like to list them by way of a table :

```
Plot[Table[a x, {a, {2, 3}}], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but both functions come out green (even without the `PlotStyle` options both lines are the same color). I am guessing that Mathematica applies the style to the table as a whole, but how do I modify the code in order to have several colors ?

Comment: Use Evaluate@Table[a x, {a, {2, 3}}]

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate

Comment: Indeed, the question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate asks why the answer to this question work. Thanks !