# Evaluating and Plotting Multiple Zero-Counting Functions

Tags: plotting, evaluation

In work that I am doing, I am trying to plot multiple zero-counting functions, depending on how a parameter works.  For example, if the zeros of one function are {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, the zeros of another function are {3, 5, 8, 12}, and the zeros of the third function are {7, 10}, my data looks like

```
SampleDats = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {3, 5, 8, 12}, {7, 10}};
```

For the counting function, the `Count` documentation gives an answer akin to

```
CountingFcn[dat_, r_] := Count[dat, u_ /; u < r];
```

which can be used on each row of the table in turn.

Of course, if I just write a Table, the `HoldAll` masks the differences between the list elements, and we get

```
PlotCountsBasic[dat_, {rMin_, rMax_}] := 
Plot[Table[CountingFcn[dat[[j, All]], r], {j, 1, Length[dat]}], {r, 
rMin, rMax}, ImageSize -> Large] ;
PlotCountsBasic[SampleDats, {0, 13}]
```

which yields [image: Evaluated in wrong order --- all blue]

So far, of course nothing is outside the scope of [Question 1731](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate).

The trouble is that when I do set `Evaluated -> True`, I get the zero-function.

```
PlotCountsEval[dat_, {rMin_, rMax_}] := 
Plot[Table[CountingFcn[dat[[j, All]], r], {j, 1, Length[dat]}], {r, 
  rMin, rMax}, ImageSize -> Large, Evaluated -> True] ;
PlotCountsEval[SampleDats, {0, 13}]
```

[image: Zero-function plots!]

This is not really an issue with `Plot`, but `Evaluate` is evaluating "too quickly" for the counting command to give any real value.  Compare:

```
Evaluate[Table[
CountingFcn[SampleDats[[j, All]], 7], {j, 1, Length[SampleDats]}]]
(*{6, 2, 0}*)
Clear[r];
Evaluate[Table[
CountingFcn[SampleDats[[j, All]], r], {j, 1, Length[SampleDats]}]]
(*{0, 0, 0}*)
```

---

**Question:** Given that the `Evaluate` trick won't work for the counting function as written, what is the best way around?  Is the right way to revise the counting-function, or is the right way to use more esoteric commands in the `Plot`?

*Configuration:* Mac OS X Yosemite (department computer), Mathematica 10.0.2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be missing the point of the question but I think you just need `_?NumericQ`:

```
ClearAll[CountingFcn]

CountingFcn[dat_, r_?NumericQ] := Count[dat, u_ /; u < r];
```

This prevents the evaluation of the function until `r` is numeric.  Now:

```
PlotCountsEval[SampleDats, {0, 13}]
```

[image]

Reference: [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html), [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html)

Comment: That's great!  +1

Comment: Now that's resolved, 1 more toward 200k...

Answer (score 5):

`Plot` is not really for discrete results like this, though one can harangue it into doing so. Better to use `DiscretePlot` or `ListPlot`, e.g.:

```
Table[CountingFcn[SampleDats[[j, All]], r], {j, 1, Length[SampleDats]}, {r, 0, 13}];

ListPlot[%, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 0,
```

DataRange -> {0, 13}]

[image]

Comment: I can't tell if this was just a convenient example for the OP; I'll hold my vote until I see what he says.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes, not completely clear from OP what's desired, so I punted...

Comment: It's a point.  However, @Mr.Wizard is correct in that I oversimplified a bit; if n(r) is the counting function, I "really" want to plot n(r)/Sqrt[r], to see this appears to approach a constant.  [I know for my functions that n(r)/Sqrt[r] is asymptotically bounded above, but not obviously asymptotically bounded below by any nonzero bound.]  The zeros of my actual functions are just some real numbers.  Of course, they are spaced out enough so that a `Listplot` would work, but I'm not yet convinced that such is the "right" way around.

Comment: Still, @rasher, your answer is a good workaround, so +1.