# Multiplying two parametric solutions

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, parametric-functions

I'm solving two (1-parameter) differential equations and I want to plot the product of their solutions, how do I do this? Here's the code,

```
Deter[p0_] := Module[{p = p0},
M = 1; m = 1; q = 1; Q = √3; d = 3; L = 1; ω = 0;

cutoff = 0.0001 ;
f[u_] = 1 - M u^(-d);
vneg[u_] = (1/√f[u]) (ω + Q q (1 - u^(2 - d))) - Q p u^(2 - d); 
vpls[u_] = (1/√f[u]) (ω + Q q (1 - u^(2 - d))) + Q p u^(2 - d);

FlowPlus[u_] = (-y[u] 2 m L u + vneg[u] - 
  k + (vpls[u] + k) y[u]^2)/(u^2  √f[u])  ;
FlowNeg[u_] = (-z[u] 2 m L u + vneg[u] + 
  k + (vpls[u] - k) z[u]^2)/(u^2  √f[u])  ;

solPlus = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[u] == FlowPlus[u], y[1 + cutoff]== I},
           y, {u, 1 + cutoff, 1/cutoff}, {k}];
solNeg = ParametricNDSolveValue[{z'[u] == FlowNeg[u], z[1 + cutoff] == I}, 
           z, {u, 1 + cutoff, 1/cutoff}, {k}];

Return[{solPlus, solNeg}]

]
```

What I want to plot is (but I'm getting a blank plot only)

```
Plot[Evaluate[Re[Deter[8][[1]][k][1/cutoff]] Re[Deter[8][[2]][k][1/cutoff]] ], {k, -5, 5},
     PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for fixing the code. I amended my answer accordingly. Is the plot I obtained what you might have expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, your `Deter` expressions are not evaluated as you expected, leaving them as non-numerical values.

Using your definition of `Deter`, and forcing evaluation of the `Plot` argument using the undocumented but well-established `Evaluated -> True` option:

```
Plot[
 Times @@ Re[Through[Through[Deter[8][k]][1/cutoff]]],
 {k, -5, 5},
 Evaluated -> True
]
```

I obtain this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See e.g. this answer from Mr. Wizard regarding the preferred use of `Evaluated -> True` over explicitly wrapping the arguments of `Plot` and the like inside an `Evaluate`: [Recommended form for evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1735/27951).

Comment: Thanks! Please note the edits I made. I some how forgot the Re[] part in the `Plot` line, but when I use your code with either `Return[{Re[solPlus], Re[solNeg]}]` or by keeping the same Return and making `.. Chop[Through[Through[Re[Deter[8][k]]][1/cutoff]]] .. ` I don't get any output. Can you please comment.

Comment: @Skylar15 Please take a look at the code I just posted. The `Re` function needs to be the outermost one in the `Through` cascade.

Comment: Oh yes.. I's just trying that. Thanks!

Comment: @Skylar15 No problem, glad it helped!

Comment: Sorry one more thing.. I'm wondering why are there two plots! In my `Plot` in the question I should get one plot which is a product of two solutions.

Comment: @Skylar15 you are quite right. I was working on each solution separately first, with the intention of plotting the product when I got them working, but forgot to multiply them at the end! See edit.

Comment: No problem. This is perfect. Thanks again!