# Why do Plot and ParametricPlot handle PlotStyle differently?

Tags: plotting

I would like to apply a custom `PlotStyle` (colors and dashing) to a plot of a bunch of expressions, which are in a nested list.  I can do this fine when using `Plot`, but with `ParametricPlot` I have to manually flatten the list of expressions.  Why do they behave differently?

I'm using *Mathematica* 10.2.

Here is an example:  I want to plot two expressions, each under two substitution rules, and use the default colors for them. I also want to show a gray dashed 45° line.  (In this example, `ParametricPlot` doesn't actually improve on `Plot`, but in my real application it does.)

```
expnList = {-.2 + x^n, 1 - x*n};
substList = {{n -> .1}, {n -> .2}};
myPlotStyle = PadRight[{Directive[Dashed, Gray]}, 5, Automatic];
```

Here's a `Plot` that works just fine:

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Prepend[x][expnList /. substList], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> myPlotStyle]
```

[image: Plot with right colors]

(I chose to use `Evaluate@` rather than `Evaluated->True` as suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1735/13293), since for some reason that fails with `ParametricPlot`.)

But when I try to make a `ParametricPlot` just like it, Mathematica thinks it's plotting just 2 lines plus the pre-pended 45° one, and so only uses 2+1 colors:

```
expnPairList = Map[{x, #} &, expnList]
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate @ Prepend[{x, x}][expnPairList /. substList], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> myPlotStyle]
```

[image: ParametricPlot with wrong colors]

I can fix this by flattening my `expnPairList` into a list of length-2 lists using `Partition` and `Flatten`.

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate @
  Prepend[{x, x}][
   Partition[#, 2] &@Flatten@(expnPairList /. substList)],
   {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> myPlotStyle]
```

[image: ParametricPlot with right colors]

What I don't understand is: Why is this flattening necessary?  I thought that using `Evaluate` would allow *Mathematica* to figure out how many lines it will need to plot, so it could assign styles appropriately.

And, is there a better way to make the colors behave correctly, without having to flatten things in this way?

Comment: The issue is not `Evaluate` but the ways that the two functions handle lists of lists.  To see this, execute `Prepend[x][expnList /. substList]` outside `Plot` and copy the result into `Plot` (without `Evaluate`), and do the similar thing for `ParametricPlot`.  You will see that the behavior is unchanged from what you describe in your question.  As I understand it, `Plot` is a special case of `ParametricPlot`.  Perhaps it flattens lists of functions before passing them to `ParametricPlot`.  It is impossible to know for certain without knowing the internal behavior of these two functions.

Comment: I don't think nested lists are a documented syntax for `Plot` or `ParametricPlot`, so I'm not sure that you can consider one behaviour correct or the other incorrect. They are different functions and they handle unsupported inputs differently. IMO flattening the lists is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a simpler approach

```
expnList = {-.2 + x^n, 1 - x*n};
myPlotStyle = PadRight[{Directive[Dashed, Gray]}, 5, Automatic];

plo = Flatten@{x, Table[expnList, {n, {.1, .2}}]}
```

[image]

```
Row[{
  Plot[
   plo, {x, 0, 1},
   ImageSize -> 400,
   PlotLabel -> "Plot",
   PlotStyle -> myPlotStyle],
  ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate@Thread[List[x, plo]], {x, 0, 1},
   ImageSize -> 400,
   PlotLabel -> "ParametricPlot",
   PlotStyle -> myPlotStyle,
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: eldo, your code is certainly cleaner.  Is there an advantage to using `Table` instead of `/.` (`ReplaceAll`) to do the substitutions for `n`?

Comment: Not really - Table is much faster for large lists (which isn't the case here). Follow your personal preference :)