# Plotting list of functions while some of them are undefined

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I'm struggling with the following code

```
f[x_] := {Undefined, x};
Plot[ f[x] , {x, 0, 1}]                    
Plot[{f[x][[1]], f[x][[2]]}, {x, 0, 1}]
f[x] == {f[x][[1]], f[x][[2]]}
```

The first plot produce blank figure and the second plot gives the graph of `x` as expected. What is puzzling, the last condition evaluates to `True`.

Can you please explain to me why the first plot gives blank plot while the second does not?

Comment: Try `Plot[Evaluate@f[x],...`

Comment: @Kuba Thank you, it works. But I can break it with `x=1` at the top, then the first plot shows one.

Comment: Yep, there is `Evaluated->True` option, but I haven't used it recently, also it is undocumented. But at least it preserves scoping.

Comment: closely related: [1731](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/5478)