# Why is this 2D plot so slow?

Tags: plotting, functions, evaluation

I first do a 3D Plot of four surfaces (eigenvalues of a $4\times4$ matrix) over $kx,kz$ (setting $ky=0$ all along). And then I try to give a 2D plot along three connected particular lines in $kx,kz$-plane, which is simply a tiny part of the 3D one. However, the 2D one turns out to be far slower than the 3D one. Also I use Evaluate in both cases, otherwise a weird mess (Why?). What's wrong with my code? And I'm wondering what the faster code ought to be.

```
zero2 = DiagonalMatrix[{0, 0}];
I2 = IdentityMatrix[2];
I4 = IdentityMatrix[4];
t = 1/2;
λ = 1;
Subscript[λ, z] = 1;
ϵ = 6 t;
b = {0, 0, 0, 1};

H[kx_, ky_, kz_] := 2 λ KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[3], PauliMatrix[1] Sin[ky] - PauliMatrix[2] Sin[kx]] + 2 Subscript[λ, z]   KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[2], I2] Sin[kz] + KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], I2] (ϵ - 2 t (Cos[kx] + Cos[ky] + Cos[kz]));
Subscript[H, 1][kx_, ky_, kz_] := b.{KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[3]], -KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[1]], KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[2]], KroneckerProduct[I2, PauliMatrix[3]]};
Eval[kx_, ky_, kz_] := FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[H[kx, ky, kz] + Subscript[H, 1][kx, ky, kz]]];

Plot3D[Evaluate[Eval[kx, 0, kz]],
  {kx, -π, π}, {kz, -π, π},
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> "Placeholder"
 ]

a0 = 1;
b1 = 2 π/a0; 
b2 = 2 π/a0; 
b3 = 2 π/a0; 
BZKx = b1/2; 
BZKz = b3/2;
Plot[Evaluate@Eval[If[k <= 0, k/Sqrt[2], If[k <= BZKx, 0, BZKx]], 0, If[k <= 0, k/Sqrt[2], If[k <= BZKx, k, k - BZKx]]],
  {k, -Sqrt[2] BZKx, 2 BZKx},
  ImageMargins -> 0, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.01]
 ]
```

[image: The 3D one][image: The 2D one]

Comment: just out of curiosity: is this a band structure of some topological insulator?

Comment: @hat That's right!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You seem to be re-evaluating the eigenvalues at every point. Just use this definition:

```
Clear[Eval,kx, ky, kz];
Eval[kx_, ky_, kz_] = 
  FullSimplify[
   Eigenvalues[H[kx, ky, kz] + Subscript[H, 1][kx, ky, kz]]];
```

Then the plots will be faster. This will symbolically evaluate the eigenvalues once, and the variables `kx, ky, kz` get substituted into the symbolic result when needed.

Regarding the need for `Evaluate` mentioned in the question, it's needed because [`Plot` has attribute `HoldAll` as explained here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate).