# List of Inequalities in RegionPlot with different colors

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, syntax

Starting from the example of the Documentation:

```
RegionPlot[{x^2 < y^3 + 1, y^2 < x^3 + 1}, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}]
```

Which gives a nice plot with two different colors for each region:

[image: documentation region plot]

I now want to provide a List of conditions to the routine instead, hence writing something similar to

```
a = {x^2 < y^3 + 1, y^2 < x^3 + 1};
RegionPlot[a, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}]
```

which should, in my naive view be equivalent but results in a loss of color differentiation:

[image]

So the question is:
**How can I pass the list to RegionPlot in order to get the same result as directly writing the list as an argument?**

Note that for a simple plot the behavior is as I would have expected it:

```
a = {x^2, x^3};
Plot[a, {x, 0, 1}]
```

(cannot show because of the link limit)

**edit:**
The behavior is new in Version 10.4.1 and was not present in 10.0 on Windows. I assumed there was a change in syntax. 
In 10.0 on Windows however there is a bug with the BoundaryStyle directive. It is ignored for a list containing more than 16 regions (for some obscure reason).

```
b = {False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 
  False, False, False, False, False, False , False, False, 
  aS <= 0 && bP >= 0, aS >= 0 && bP >= 0 }
RegionPlot[b, {aS, -0.5, 1.}, {bP, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotPoints -> 50,
 FrameLabel -> {"S", "P"},
 PlotStyle -> colors,
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 22},
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], Mesh -> None]
```

Comment: No such behavior on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014), use ClearAll["Global`*"] FHS

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that before. The behavior is new in Version 10.4.1 and was not present in 10.0 on Windows.
I thought there was a change in syntax.
In 10.0 on Windows however the BoundaryStyle directive is ignored for a list containing more than 16 regions (for some obscure reason).

Comment: @Andre Because of the `HoldAll` attribute of the plotting functions, you need to evaluate the list $a$ so `RegionPlot` recognizes that it is a list and attempts to use multiple colors: `RegionPlot[Evaluate@a, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}]`.

Comment: For instance the problem was discussed in the case of `Plot` before: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/27951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding links to comment by MarcoB

Note the [Attributes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes.html) of [RegionPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html)

```
Attributes[RegionPlot]

(*  {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}  *)
```

Since `RegionPlot` and other plot functions have attribute [HoldAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) you need to use [Evaluate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html)

```
a = {x^2 < y^3 + 1, y^2 < x^3 + 1};
RegionPlot[Evaluate[a], {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was mainly confused because of the change of behaviour upon updating from 10.0 to 10.4.