# How to draw several regions using one function returning List of True's and False's?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

This is what I want:

```
RegionPlot[
{
   y < x^2,
   y < 0.5 + 0.5 x
},
{x, 0, 2},
{y, 0, 4}
]
```

This code does not work (draws only one region):

```
rf[x_, y_] := {
   y < x^2,
   y < 0.5 + 0.5 x
};
RegionPlot[
 rf[x, y],
 {x, 0, 2},
 {y, 0, 4}
]
```

Actual function `rf` is very complex (CPU consuming), and I don't want to calculate it twice like here:

```
(* it works, but calculates rf twice *)
rf[x_, y_] := {
   y < x^2,
   y < 0.5 + 0.5 x
};
RegionPlot[
 {rf[x, y][[1]], rf[x, y][[2]]},
 {x, 0, 2},
 {y, 0, 4}
]
```

Using `Map` does not help:

```
rf[x_, y_] := {
   y < x^2,
   y < 0.5 + 0.5 x
};
RegionPlot[
 {#[[1]], #[[2]]}& /@ rf[x, y],
 {x, 0, 2},
 {y, 0, 4}
]
```

> ```
> ImplicitRegion::bcond: {y,x^2}&&{y,0.5 +0.5 x} should be a Boolean combination of equations, inequalities, and Element statements.
> ```

Comment: `RegionPlot[Evaluate@rf[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 4}]`

Comment: closely related: [113958](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113958/5478)

Answer (score 2):

You can memoize the complex function so that it is only called once for a particular value of $x$ and $y$:

```
Clear[z];
z[x_, y_] := z[x,y] = {y<x^2, y<.5+.5x}

RegionPlot[
    {Indexed[z[x, y], 1], Indexed[z[x, y], 2]},
    {x, 0, 2},
    {y, 0, 4}
]
```

[image]