# Trying to plot predefined function list, PlotLegends option fails using legend list

Tags: plotting

I am trying to predefine the functions I want to plot. A minimal example of what I am trying to achieve looks like this:

```
fToPlot = {x, 2 x};
legendToPlot = {"x", "2x"};
Plot[fToPlot, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> legendToPlot]
```

To my suprise this produces the following output:

[image]

which omits the second entry of the legendToPlot list completely. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: The behavior you observe is likely to be linked with the one explained here: [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/27951).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Plot` interprets `fToPlot` as a single item rather than a list.  Thus you must `Evaluate` it:

```
fToPlot = {x, 2 x};
legendToPlot = {"x", "2x"};
Plot[Evaluate@fToPlot, 
     {x, 0, 5}, 
     PlotLegends -> legendToPlot]
```

Note that:

```
fToPlot = {x, 2 x};
Plot[Evaluate@fToPlot, 
    {x, 0, 5}, 
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

also works.

Comment: The option `Evaluated ->True` can also be used here, I think.

Comment: @J.M.  Nope.  Doesn't work.  Didn't you try it?

Comment: Interesting, what version are you using? `Plot[fToPlot, {x, 0, 5}, Evaluated -> True, PlotLegends -> legendToPlot]`works on 10.4.1 here. EDIT: Huh, the legends get messed up. This sure looks like a bug...

Comment: 10.4.0.0 on a Mac.  I'm not sure your option `Evaluated` is appropriate here.

Comment: @J.M. - Since at least version 7.0.1, `Evaluated` is not a documented option for `Plot` or `Graphics` from which `Plot` inherits many of its options. Consequently, none of its behavior can properly be a bug.