# Problem with PolarPlot and Table

Tags: plotting, syntax

If I have a set of numbers, for example

```
grid = N[Table[n^2/2, {n, 3, 24}]]
```

And want to plot that as circles I can either use Graphics[] and Circle[], or PolarPlot[]. With the latter there seems to be some problem that I don't understand:

If I plot

```
PolarPlot[grid, {h, 0, 300}]
```

the output makes no sense, but if i paste the output list by hand:

```
PolarPlot[{4.5, 8., 12.5, 18.}, {h, 0, 300}]
```

it works. Why is that? Screenshot with Out[2] as the corrupted output, and Out[3] as it should be:

[image]

Comment: Use `Evaluate@grid` instead of `grid`, so that `PolarPlot` may become aware of the list structure of your input. This will then be [the result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BAXHz.png). `PolarPlot` has `Hold` attributes, like most of the plotting functions, so it won't evaluate its arguments otherwise. See [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/27951).

Comment: That answers the question, but since it is just a comment I can't give you reputation