# Multiple plot for 2 variables function

Tags: plotting

I have a 2 variables function as below:

```
m[n_] := 1.5 n^2
V[n_, r_] := (m[n]*m[n])/((r)^3)
```

On the range of r from 1 to 20 I want to make 30 plot (30 different colors) for each state n =1,2,3....up to 30. I can use the command Plot which is

```
Plot[{V[1, r], V[2, r], V[3, r], V[4, r]}, {r, 1, 20}]
```

by that I have to to 30 times V[n,r] which is doable in this case, but suppose I want n up to 1000, do you guys have any ideas for this case please.

Comment: I believe you want `Plot[Table[V[i, r], {i, 30}], {r, 1, 20}, Evaluated -> True]`?  If so we can mark this as already answered here: [(1731)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/121)

Comment: Thank you for answering my dumb question. That is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You are welcome.  Dumb question?  Not in my opinion.  From the number of votes on the existing question linked above I'd say not in a lot of other people's opinions either.  Nevertheless I shall mark this as "already has an answer."