# ReplaceAll and PlotStyle and PlotLegends in multiple curves

Tags: graphics

Why do `PlotStyle` and `PlotLegends` take only a single style for all the curves if `ReplaceAll` rule is outside the bracket?

```
Plot[{α x, x^2 α} /. {α -> 2.5}, {x, -2, 6}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 6}, {-1, 6}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Dotted, Blue, Thick}, {Dashed, Red}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> {"V[ϕ]", "ϵ[ϕ]"}
]
```

Versus

```
Plot[{α x /. {α -> 2.5}, x^2 α /. {α -> 2.5}}, {x, -2, 6}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 6}, {-1, 6}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Dotted, Blue, Thick}, {Dashed, Red}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> {"V[ϕ]", "ϵ[ϕ]"}
]
```

The behavior is same even for `ParametricPlot` and for more than two curves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Plot` has `Hold` attributes, like all the other plotting functions. This means that sometimes it does not not recognize the fact that its argument is a list if the head of that argument is not explicitly `List`. See: [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/27951).

In your first case, the head of the expression in the first argument of `Plot` is `ReplaceAll` before evaluation, so `Plot` sets up a single style for it:

```
HoldForm[{α x, x^2 α} /. {α -> 2.5}] // FullForm

(* Out: 
HoldForm[ReplaceAll[
  List[Times[α, x], Times[Power[x, 2], α]], 
  List[Rule[α, 2.5]]
 ]
]
*)
```

In your second case, the head of the expression is `List`, so `Plot` recognizes that it needs to use more than one style:

```
HoldForm[{α x /. {α -> 2.5}, x^2 α /. {α -> 2.5}}] // FullForm

(* Out: 
HoldForm[
 List[
  ReplaceAll[Times[α, x], List[Rule[α, 2.5]]], 
  ReplaceAll[Times[Power[x, 2], α], List[Rule[α, 2.5]]]
 ]
]
*)
```

As usual, the solution is to explicitly `Evaluate` the first argument:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{α x, x^2 α} /. {α -> 2.5}], {x, -2, 6},
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 6}, {-1, 6}},
 PlotStyle -> {{Dotted, Blue, Thick}, {Dashed, Red}},
 Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> {"V[ϕ]", "ϵ[ϕ]"}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1.This answer in combination with Matariki's answer to the linked question makes the stucture of HoldAll,  ReplaceAll,  within the context of plotting functions and how Evaluate can change the head to List for desired result.

Comment: Problem: even though the head of {{\[Alpha] x, x^2 \[Alpha]} /. {\[Alpha] -> 2.5}} is list, still plot showing single style!