# Plot Function is not Coloring different plots correctly

Tags: plotting, color, list-manipulation

I am trying to plot three fits simultaneously:

```
Plot[Table[#[x, t], {t, {1, 3, 5}}], {x, -10, 10}] & /@ ϕContfit
```

Where ϕContfit is a list of fits, each of two variables x ant t, from NonlinearModelFit. I am making a list of plots, where each plot will show the fit at t = 1, 3, and 5 for x in the range of -10 to 10.

The documentation of the Plot function indicates that the following code

```
Plot[{f1,f2,...},{x,xmin,xmax}]
```

should plot each function and automatically color each function with a different color; however, when I run the first line shown above each plot colors the functions the same. Here is one element of the list of plots:

[image: Three plots have the same color]

If I try to indicate the style of each function, it just gives all three the last color (in this case, green):

```
Plot[Table[#[x, t], {t, {1, 3, 5}}], {x, -10, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}] & /@ ϕContfit
```

However, if instead of using the Table function I explicitly write out the functions:

```
Plot[{#[x, 1], #[x, 3], #[x, 5]}, {x, -10, 10}] & /@ ϕContfit
```

then the Plot function colors everything fine (each functions is automatically colored differently).

I want to generalize this to different plots, different values, etc., so it would be helpful if I could use the Table (or some other) function to color everything correctly. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Just need to add an Evaluate function:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[#[x, t], {t, {1, 3, 5}}], {x, -10, 
10}] & /@ ϕContfit
```