# PlotLegends in Plot of List passed as reference

Tags: plotting, legending

When I pass the list directly into the Plot as

```
Plot[{1 x, 2 x, 3 x}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> {1, 2, 3}]
```

the legends are

[image: legends2]

But when I pass a reference to the list into the Plot as

```
l = {1 x, 2 x, 3 x}
Plot[l, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> {1, 2, 3}]
```

the legends are

[image: legends1]

How can I get all legends displayed after passing a list reference and not a plain list to the Plot?

The version of Wolfram Mathematica is 10.4.0.0.

Comment: Wrap `l` in `Evaluate`. See the answers in this question for why: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/6588

Comment: Thank you! It works as expected.