# Plot a loop using the same function

Tags: plotting

To generate a plot of multiple functions, I currently use this syntax:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

This generates a plot of 3 functions as shown below.
[image]

I would like to fund out if there is a way to instead loop through values of i = 1, 2 and 3 plotting the function y = Sin(ix) to come up with the same result.

Comment: try `Plot[Evaluate[Sin[# x] & /@ Range[3]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`?

Comment: Or `Plot[Evaluate@Table[Sin[i x], {i, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: Both of these work. Why does Plot [Table[Sin[i x], {i, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] provide the plot but not the different colors?

Comment: @user32882 http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/5478

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate)