# Plotting multiple functions in one plot using iterative variable

Tags: plotting

This is a followup to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135170/plot-a-loop-using-the-same-function?noredirect=1#comment364694_135170) question.

The following code `Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]` results in the following plot: [image]

The following code:

```
Plot [Table[Sin[i x], {i, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Results in the following plot:

[image]

This is kind of strange, specifically since the output of `Table[Sin[i x], {i, 1, 3}]`

Equals `{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}`

Are these not essentially identical expressions? Why is Mathematica not producing the same plot?

Comment: Because the input is different. In the first plot you have 3 functions, in the second `Table` is interpreted as one. Wrap the `Table` in `Evaluate`, it will look the same as the first plot.

Comment: The difference is that `Plot` has the `HoldAll` attribute, so in the first case, `Plot` is fed something that is already a list of three expressions by the time `Plot` evaluates, while in the second case, the `Table` has not yet evaluated into a list of three expressions. Add `Evaluate@` in front of `Table` to circumvent the `HoldAll` attribute.

Comment: Indeed when I do this Plot [Evaluate[Table[Sin[i x], {i, 1, 3}]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]. It comes out with the different colors. Thanks.

Comment: Another possibie syntax is `Plot[Table[Sin[i x], {i, 1, 3}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Evaluated -> True]`