# Why these functions have the same color?

Tags: plotting

I have this code

```
f[x_, n_] := Sum[ComplexExpand@Abs[Sin[x + k]], {k, 0, n}]
Plot[Table[f[x, n], {n, 0, 5}], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

but the graph is all of the same color instead of color differently each function. How I can change this? Thank you.

Comment: Try this `Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[x, n], {n, 0, 5}], {x, -Pi, Pi}]`

Comment: @Maple this worked totally!!! What kind of magic is this?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate