# List inside `DiscretePlot` make functions of the same color

Tags: plotting

I know that the behavior of plotting different functions in the same color when we are using a `Table` [can be fixed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate) using `Evaluate`. But I dont know how to fix the same behavior when we have a list instead of a table.

The example

```
(* Our pseudo-generating function *)
g[x_, m_, bigD_, t_, d_, 
  c_] := ((c/bigD)/x + (bigD - t - c)/
     bigD + (t - d) x/bigD + (d/bigD) x^2)^m

 (* Probability mass function of k *)
f[k_, m_, bigD_, t_, d_, c_] := 
 If[k == 0, 
  Sum[Coefficient[g[x, m, bigD, t, d, c], x, i], {i, -m, 0}], 
  Coefficient[g[x, m, bigD, t, d, c], x, k]]

 (* We make a first probability distribution *)
dist[m_, bigD_: 6, t_: 2, d_: 0, c_: 0] := 
  ProbabilityDistribution[f[k, m, bigD, t, d, c], {k, 0, 2 m, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> {bigD \[Element] Integers, 0 <= d < bigD, 
     0 <= c < bigD, 1 <= t < bigD, m \[Element] Integers && m > 0}];

(* Other probability mass function *)
h[k_, m_, bigD_, t_, d_, c_] := 
 If[k < m, f[k, m, bigD, t, d, c], 
  Sum[Coefficient[g[x, m, bigD, t, d, c], x, i], {i, m, 2 m}]]

(* Our probability distribution using the function h *)
dist2[m_, bigD_: 6, t_: 2, d_: 0, c_: 0] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[h[j, m, bigD, t, d, c], {j, 0, m, 1},
  Assumptions -> {bigD \[Element] Integers, 0 <= d < bigD, 
    0 <= c < bigD, 1 <= t < bigD, m \[Element] Integers && m > 0}]

(* Now we compare dist and dist2 when d\[NotEqual]0 *)
DiscretePlot[
 Evaluate@PDF[#[5, 6, 2, 1, 1], k] & /@ {dist, dist2}, {k, 0, 10}, 
 ExtentSize -> 3/4]
```

In the last cell `DiscretePlot` graph the two PDF of the same color, how I can fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate)

Comment: @corey979 it is not a duplicate, as I explained in the first paragraph.

Comment: ??... A `List` is an output of a `Table`. // Or it might even be "a simple mistake..." as the precedence can be found in the docs/on this site, and the answer introduces only a bracket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with operator precedence. You should write

```
DiscretePlot[
 Evaluate@(PDF[#[5, 6, 2, 1, 1], k] & /@ {dist, dist2}), {k, 0, 10}, 
 ExtentSize -> 3/4]
```

instead, because `@` has higher precedence than `/@`

Comment: Thank you very much, its solved! I cant accept the answer by now (the threshold of 10 minutes was not reached) but I will.