# Function plotting in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I want to plot following function in Mathematica:

$f(x) = \frac{x}{x+c}$

I used the following command.

```
ListPlot[x/(x+c), {c, 1,10}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}]
```

But it does not give me legends like which plot belongs to which value of c.
Need help ASAP.

Comment: Use `Plot3D[x/(x+c),{c,1,10},{x,0,10}]` or if you want to plot your function multiple times for different `c`, use `Plot[Evaluate@Table[x/(x+c),{c,1,10}],{x,0,10}]`

Comment: @JulienKluge: What i wrote does the trick but I want mathematica to  show me which plot corresponds to which value of c.

Comment: See my answer. And no, your given code isn't even valid MMA code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really use [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[x/(x+c),{c,1,10}],{x,0,10},PlotLegends->"Expressions"]
```

evaluates to:

[image]

Explanation:

1.

```
Table[x/(x+c),{c,1,10}]
```

Evaluates to your functions, for the given Range of `c`.

> `{x/(1+x),x/(2+x),x/(3+x),x/(4+x),x/(5+x),x/(6+x),x/(7+x),x/(8+x),x/(9+x),x/(10+x)}`

2.

```
Evaluate@Table[...
```

[`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) forces Mathematica to evaluate the [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)-expression. This must be done, because `Plot` holds its arguments. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate).

3.

```
PlotLegends->"Expressions"
```

Is an option for `Plot` and says Mathematica, that it should use the function-expressions as PlotLegends.

Comment: How to get values of c in legend

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html