# How to automate plotting of many functions?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Consider

`Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]`

versus

```
Plot[Table[Sin[x + i Pi/2], {i, 0, 1}], {x, 0, 10}]
```

The first command produces two plots (with different colors)

[image]

and the second produces one double-plot

[image]

My question is, how can I automatically generate a list of functions (as I attempted with the Table command) that is treated as a list of separate functions (with different colors and styles) by the Plot function?

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate@Table[Sin[x + i Pi/2], {i, 0, 1}], {x, 0, 10}]`

Comment: Thanks! Maybe post this as an answer?

Comment: The question was already answered on several places. I flagged it as duplicate. You can see one discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/34848).