# PlotLegends with Expressions from Table don't show up

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Let's say I have a plot:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Everything is fine. But if I write:

```
sins = Table[Sin[n x], {n, 1, 2}]
Plot[sins, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

then the legend doesn't show up. Why and how do I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) on the list inside `Plot` should help `Plot` "[see](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate)" the expressions:

```
sins = Table[Sin[n x], {n, 1, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate@sins, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Plot of sins with PlotLegends giving the expressions in sins]

Hopefully that helps!