# plotting several curves with the same function

Tags: plotting, replacement

Instead of using `Show[Plot[f[x]/.{L->1},{x,0,1}],Plot[f[x]/.{L->2},{x,0,1}], Plot[f[x]/.{L->3},{x,0,1}]]`, I was wondering if there is a much simpler way by using some sort of replacing rule. Something like `Plot[f[x]/.{L->1,L->2,L->3},{x,0,1}]`, and have the three curves on the same plot. Does Mathematica support something like this?

Comment: Either `{{L -> 1}, {L -> 2}, {L -> 3}}` or take a look at Table etc. Related: [1731](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us fix the function f for this example, say, this way:

```
f[x_, L_] := (x/L)^2;
```

Then try this:

```
Plot[f[x, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

or this:

```
Plot[Table[f[x, L], {L, {1, 2, 3}}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

or this:

```
Plot[Thread[f[x, #] &[{1, 2, 3}]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

They all return the following plot:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Recommend that you also include use of `Evaluate` to distinguish between plots.

Answer (score 3):

Amplifying on Alexei's answer

```
f[x_, L_] := (x/L)^2;
```

Either

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[x, L], {L, {1, 2, 3}}], {x, 0, 1},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.25, .75}]]
```

or

```
Plot[Evaluate[f[x, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}], {x, 0, 1},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.25, .75}]]
```

produce

[image]