# Plotting Solve output automatically

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, eigenvalues

I am trying to solve a characteristic polynomial and plotting its output.
The problem is that I do not know how to take the output automatically. 
My current code is

```
det2 = -λ^3 - λ^2*(p1 + p2) + λ*(p1 - p2)^2 + p3^3 + (p1 - p2)^2*(p1 + p2)

sol = Solve[det2 == 0, λ] /. {p3 -> 1 - p1 - p2, p1 -> 0}
```

with the output

```
{{λ -> 1/3 (-p2 - (4 2^(1/3) p2^2)/(-27 (1 - p2)^3 - 16 p2^3 + 
        3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[27 (1 - p2)^6 + 32 (1 - p2)^3 p2^3])^(1/3) - 
       (-27 (1 - p2)^3 - 16 p2^3 + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[27 (1 - p2)^6 + 
       32 (1 - p2)^3 p2^3])^(1/3)/2^(1/3))}, 
{λ -> -(p2/3) + (2 2^(1/3) (1 + I Sqrt[3]) p2^2)/(
    3 (-27 (1 - p2)^3 - 16 p2^3 + 
       3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[27 (1 - p2)^6 + 32 (1 - p2)^3 p2^3])^(
     1/3)) + ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-27 (1 - p2)^3 - 16 p2^3 + 
       3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[27 (1 - p2)^6 + 32 (1 - p2)^3 p2^3])^(1/3))/(
    6 2^(1/3))}, 
{λ -> -(p2/3) + (2 2^(1/3) (1 - I Sqrt[3]) p2^2)/(3 (-27 
      (1 - p2)^3 - 16 p2^3 + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[27 (1 - p2)^6 + 
      32 (1 - p2)^3 p2^3])^(1/3)) + ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-27 
      (1 - p2)^3 - 16 p2^3 + 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[27 (1 - p2)^6 + 
      32 (1 - p2)^3 p2^3])^(1/3))/(6 2^(1/3))}}
```

Usually I take the output manually. In this case I would create a three objects

```
eps1 = lambda1 (first solve output)
eps2 = lambda2 (second solve output)
eps3 = lambda3 (third solve output)
```

and finally

```
 Plot[
   {eps1, eps2, eps3}, {p2, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.4, 1}}, 
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions", GridLines -> Automatic
 ]
```

The problem is that this is a small example, but I have to do this several times for bigger matrices. Is there a way to plot the outputs in a more efficient manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your replacement in the definition of `sol` does not work as you wrote it; since you have `p1` in the first replacement rule, you either `chain` the two rules (i.e. `/. p3 -> 1 - p1 - p2 /. p1 -> 0`, or you use `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) with the list.

You then can use a replacement within `Plot` to get what you want no matter how many solutions you seek. Note that you want to `Evaluate` the argument of `Plot` so that `Plot` can realize that it is a list and color your curves appropriately:

```
det2 = -λ^3 - λ^2*(p1 + p2) + λ*(p1 - p2)^2 + p3^3 + (p1 - p2)^2*(p1 + p2)
sol = Solve[det2 == 0, λ] //. {p3 -> 1 - p1 - p2, p1 -> 0}

Plot[Evaluate[Abs@λ /. sol], {p2, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(The need for `Evaluate` stems from the `HoldAll` attribute of `Plot`, see [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/27951).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sol = Solve[det2 == 0, λ] /. p3 -> 1 - p1 - p2 /. p1 -> 0
Plot[
  λ /. sol, {p2, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.4, 1}}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions", GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Only one solution is plotted because some complex λ

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I forgot to take the absolute value in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
eps1 = sol[[1, All]];

eps2 = sol[[2, All]];

eps3 = sol[[3, All]];

Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@{eps1, eps2, eps3} /. {p1 -> 0}, {p2, 0.01, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason, I could not be able to make the plot, I ended with an empty plot. At the end, to make the plot I used `eps=sol[[All, 1, 2]]` and `eps[[1]]`, `eps[[2]]`, `eps[[3]]`; I have to admit that I am still trying to understand the syntax.