# Issue passing a list to last argument of ImplicitRegion (Scope issue?)

Tags: functions, variable-definitions

This is a very strange issue I'm having trying to pass a list as an argument to Mathematica's "ImplicitRegion" function. Here's the issue:

```
basis = Array[e, 2]
Norm[basis, 1]
reg = ImplicitRegion[Norm[basis, 1] < 1, basis]
```

> ```
> (* {e[1], e[2]} *)
> (* Abs[e[1]] + Abs[e[2]] *)
> (* ImplicitRegion[Norm[basis, 1] < 1, {basis}] *)
> ```

You can see that, for some reason, the variable "basis" isn't getting substituted correctly into the last call to `ImplicitRegion`. There is no problem passing it to `Norm`, it's only `ImplicitRegion`. In particular, it seems to be the last argument.

For instance, if I change it to this, you can that `Norm[basis, 1]` gets substituted correctly to `Abs[e[1]] + Abs[e[2]] < 1` in the last `ImplicitRegion` call:

```
basis = Array[e, 2]
Norm[basis, 1]
reg = ImplicitRegion[Norm[basis, 1] < 1, {e[1], e[2]}]
```

> ```
> (* {e[1], e[2]} *)
> (* Abs[e[1]] + Abs[e[2]] *)
> (* ImplicitRegion[Abs[e[1]] + Abs[e[2]] < 1, {e[1], e[2]}] *)
> ```

ImplicitRegion wants the last parameter to be a List, so it isn't seem like I should be using Apply or something.

How do I get this to substitute correctly? Is it a scope issue?

Comment: See the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/9490)

Comment: Aha, thanks! Didn't realize the Hold[] was there. Works with an explicit Evaluate[]