# How to Plot several functions using differents colors , It is possible to use TeX or MathSymbols?

Tags: plotting, latex, plot-themes

The question is to plot several functions with different colors. Using a Table, which contains important information into it.

You can see in the example above three functions with different values for each graph. However, in this example, **all the curves are blue**, I would like to show them **differently.**

Also, I would like to add it a caption, titles in Latex, i.e, superscript, vectors, etc. but it doesn´t work well.

Of course,  after using the basic Math assistant but it does not work properly The output is wrong, (for example, something like that \vec{f}_x to call the function complaining. Here it is the code and the plot;

[image]

```
 Clear["Global`*"]; 

L = 15; pp = 100; k = 1;
v[x_] = {Sin[( n + 1) k  x], Cos[ n  k  x],   x Sin[n x k]}  ; 

graf1 = Table[Plot[v[x], {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> Full], {n, 0, 2}];

TableForm[{graf1}, TableHeadings -> {TextCell[StringJoin[{"f", ToString@#}], 
      FontSize -> 12] & /@ {X, Y, Z }, 
   TextCell[StringJoin[{"n = ", ToString@#}], FontSize -> 12] & /@ 
    Range[0, 3]}, TableAlignments -> Center, TableSpacing -> {1, 1}]
```

Comment: I do not understand what the question is here. Please rephrase it. Make sure it is clear, concise, unambiguous, and most importantly: there is an explicitly stated and focused question.

Comment: You can see that each panel have three different plots, How to put each one using a  different color (Black, red, Brown).  and how to add Latex Symbols in the caption?

Comment: Please separate unrelated questions. The plotting one has been asked many times, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/12  The LaTeX one I still do not understand. Please show a concrete example: this is what I tried, this is what happened, this is what I expected to happen instead.

Comment: Of course, I reviewed all of these examples them, It does not work for this case.  Try to run the code before to write an incorrect answer here

Comment: If you add `//Evaluate` as in `graf1 = Table[
  Plot[v[x] // Evaluate, {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> Full], {n, 0, 2}]` ?

Comment: "Try to run the code before to write an incorrect answer here" The issue is precisely what I linked to and adding `Evaluate` fixes it. Try it. `Plot[v[x] // Evaluate, ...`

Comment: sure, excuse the misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
graf1 = Table[
 Plot[v[x] // Evaluate, {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> Full],   {n, 0, 2}];
 TableForm[{graf1}, 
TableHeadings -> {TextCell[Subscript[f, #], 
  FontSize -> 12] & /@ {x, y, z}, 
 TextCell[StringJoin[{"n = ", ToString@#}], FontSize -> 12] & /@ 
Range[0, 3]}, TableAlignments -> Center, TableSpacing -> {1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, this plot works great, also It can accept directly to use Greek letters from Palettes but in order to use operators symbols quotation marks as "  "  has to be used,  Thanks!.