# Different colors for each curve in a Plot[Table[],{}]

Tags: plotting, color, list-manipulation

I'd like to plot a few curves in a plot but with different colors, like in this code :

```
f[x_, a_] = x*Log[x] + (1 - x)*Log[1 - x] - a*x^2 ;
Plot[Table[f[x, a], {a, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}}], {x, 0.0001, 0.9999}]
```

But I'm getting all of them in blue !

[image: plot]

What can I do ?

Comment: `Attributes[Plot]` shows that `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll`. `Evaluate` the `Table` to override the `HoldAll`.

Comment: I am certain this is a dupe...

Comment: @J.M. is [(1731)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/121) good enough?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, my memory is going really bad as of late; I should have known we've made it an FAQ. :)

Comment: @J.M. I know the feeling, believe me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way

```
 f[x_,a_]=x*Log[x]+(1-x)*Log[1-x]-a*x^2;
 Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[x, a], {a, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}}], {x, 0.0001, 0.9999}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would also consider changing your definition from `f[x_,a_]=x*Log[x]+(1-x)*Log[1-x]-a*x^2;` to `f[x_,a_]:=x*Log[x]+(1-x)*Log[1-x]-a*x^2;`