# Plotting solution of differential equation

Tags: plotting

```
M1 = Array[Subscript[y, #1, #2][t] &, {2, 2}];
M0 = {{1, 0.00001}, {0.00001, 0}};
ci = Thread[Flatten[M1] == Flatten[M0]] /. {t -> 0};
s = NDSolve[{ I D[M1, t] == (M''.M1 - M1.M'')/20, ci}, Variables[M1], {t, 0, 10}]
```

I have solved the above differential equation. It gives 4 different solutions i.e. the 4 different matrix elements of M1 as the interpolating functions.

How to plot these different solutions. I tried doing

```
Plot[M1 /. s, {t, 0, 10}]
```

but it is not showing anything. 
Sorry I forgot to mention, M'' is defined as a matrix

```
M''={{3.58368*10^-6, -9.3358*10^-6}, {-9.3358*10^-6, -3.58368*10^-6}}
```

It is showing solution as

```
> {{Subscript[y, 1, 1][t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][t], 



Subscript[y, 1, 2][t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][t], 


 Subscript[y, 2, 1][t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][t], 


 Subscript[y, 2, 2][t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>][t]}}
```

Comment: `NDSolve` is not producing a solution, so there is nothing for `Plot` to plot.  At least one problem with your code is that `M` is undefined.  By the way, it is prudent not to begin variable names with capital letters.

Comment: The solutions are going to be complex-valued, so you might try `ReImPlot` instead of `Plot`.

Comment: And `M''` is shorthand for `Derivative[2][M]`, which seems a somewhat hacky way to store a constant matrix.

Comment: I tried but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
M'' = {{3.58368*10^-6, -9.3358*10^-6}, {-9.3358*10^-6, -3.58368*10^-6}}    

M1 = Array[Subscript[y, #1, #2][t] &, {2, 2}];
M0 = {{1, 0.00001}, {0.00001, 0}};
ci = Thread[Flatten[M1] == Flatten[M0]] /. {t -> 0};
s = NDSolve[{I D[M1, t] == (M''.M1 - M1.M'')/20, ci}, 
  Variables[M1], {t, 0, 10}]

ReImPlot[M1 /. s, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

To get different colors, you need to evaluate the argument (this is addressed [elsewhere on this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate)):

```
ReImPlot[M1 /. s // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

One can see from comparing the results, there's a scaling issue in plotting.  Probably, the best thing to do is to plot the components separately:

```
ReImPlot[#, {t, 0, 10}] & /@ Flatten[M1 /. s] // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

Hmm, labels might be nice:

```
ReImPlot[# /. s, {t, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> #] & /@ 
  Flatten@M1 // GraphicsRow
```

Comment: Using `M''` as a variable seems bad practice to me, but I just copied the OP's code.

Comment: Sorry, but can u please let me know which version of Mathematica you are using as this command is not working for me. Also, what are those which are shown as solutions to the differential equation as they seem to be sinusoidal curves (the ones which are shown as interpolating functions)? Are they not the solutions?  But here, the solutions seem to be something else.

Comment: @MadhurimaChakraborty V12.  In V10.1 and later you can use `Plot[ReIm[# /. s]//Evaluate, ...`.  In earlier versions, you can use `Plot[{Re[#] /. First[s], Im[#] /. First[s]},...`.  You might need `First[s]` in the V10 code -- I can't test it. (You said, "the command" but I don't know what that means. I assumed `ReImPlot`.)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @MadhurimaChakraborty You're welcome. If you want to see sinusoidal plots, you need to integrate and then plot out to `t -> 10^7` or more (because the coefficients are on the order of `10^-7`).

Comment: By sinusoidal plots I meant the ones which come as solutions of s = NDSolve[{I D[M1, t] == (M''.M1 - M1.M'')/20, ci}, 
  Variables[M1], {t, 0, 10}]. What about them?

Comment: @MadhurimaChakraborty That's what I'm talking about. They are sinusoidal, with a period of about t = 6 x 10^6.  See http://i.stack.imgur.com/DIpeS.png

Comment: okay. Thank you.