# How can I plot a parametric equation with ±?

Tags: plotting, core-language

I want to draw a parametric equation with ± like the figure below:

[image]

But I don't get the result I want when I run the following code. What can I do to get it?

```
ParametricPlot[{x, ±x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Mesh -> 30, PlotPoints -> 50, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: `PlusMinus` is for display purposes.  It has no builtin meaning.  It is not an operator that returns a value.  The plot would normally be produced with `Plot[{x^2, -x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, Mesh -> 30, AspectRatio -> 2, 
 PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.37, 0.51, 0.71]}]`  but you could use `ParametricPlot[{Abs[x], Sign[x] x^2}, {x, -1, 1}, Mesh -> 60, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]`

Comment: @LouisB Thank you. I just want to know if MMA has similar multivalued functions participating in drawing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This formulation might be useful to you.

```
±b_ := {b, -b}

ParametricPlot[Thread[{x, ±x^2}], {x, 0, 1}, Mesh -> 30, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

#### Notes

- This will expand appearances of ±value outside of plotting as well.  If you need ± to persist in data this expansion should be restricted.  We can write a custom plotting function, say `parametricPlot`, that performs this and other expansions, then hands off the data to `ParametricPlot`.
- The form used above results in shared styling between the positive and negative branches. Reference: [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/121)

Answer (score 8):

You can just do

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, x^2}, {x, -x^2}}, {x, 0, 1}, Mesh -> 30, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]