# Variable limit of the plot range

Tags: plotting

I have a line of code `K1=1; Plot[ Table[K1 xt x - K1 x^2,{xt,0.5,2.5,0.2}],{x,0,1}]`. It generates multiple plot for on the same figure but whenever x > xt, value becomes negative which I don't need in the plot. Is there a way to do something like this `Plot[Table[K1 xt x - K1 x^2,{xt,0.5,2.5,0.2}],{x,0,xt}]`. Whenever I run the 2nd command it returns a error saying Limiting value xt is not a machine sized real number(I think it basically need a constant to be there).

Comment: It’ll be helpful to include definition for `K1`.

Comment: @CATrevillian K1=1

Comment: Why not just change the `PlotRange` to remove the negative y-axis?

Comment: @CATrevillian Is there a better approach than adjusting the PlotRange?

Comment: Probably what kglr just posted :) but it ultimately depends on what you want to do with the plot/data/lines afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) or [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)  or [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) as follows:

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[ConditionalExpression[K1 xt x - K1 x^2, x <= xt],
    {xt, 0.5, 2.5, 0.2}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[Piecewise[{{K1 xt x - K1 x^2, x <= xt}}, Undefined], 
  {xt, 0.5, 2.5, 0.2}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> ```
>  same picture
> ```

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[K1 xt x - K1 x^2, {xt, 0.5, 2.5, 0.2}], 
  {x, 0, 1}, RegionFunction -> (#2 >= 0 &)]
```

[image]

Comment: You know what I tried with piecewise but my x-axis was getting covered with the curve, I didn't know about the ```Undefined``` thing. Also, do you know the reason behind using ```Evaluate``` to get the coloured curves and without it, all the curves are of the same color.

Comment: @AQ, re the need for `Evaluate` please see [this answer by Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1735/125)