# Why does Plot function have HoldAll attribute?

Tags: plotting, evaluation, hold, language-design

I had an odd issue where my plot wasn't drawn correctly when I called it via `Plot[Join[fs,gs], (*..*)]`. However, these two versions worked:

```
funcs = Join[fs,gs]; Plot[funcs, (*..*)]           (*1*)

plot[fs_] := Plot[fs,(*..*)]
plot[Join[fs,gs]]                                  (*2*)
```

After a bit of playing around and a bit of research, I found out that explicitly `Evaluate`-ing the `Join` expression fixes the plot, so

```
Plot[Evaluate[Join[fs,gs]],(*..*)]                 (*3*)
```

works the same way as the two other examples. It turns out, `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll` set whereas `Set` and `SetDelayed` do not.

Hence I suspect that $(1)$ and $(2)$ evaluate the Join expression before passing it to the plot. But

1. Is there a reason why `Plot` holds its arguments?
2. Does that mean if my expression for the plot gets more intricate, I should always `Evaluate` just to be sure? The documentation just says

> In some cases, it may be more efficient to use Evaluate to evaluate f symbolically before specific numerical values are assigned to x.

Comment: I believe it's to allow `Plot` to localize the independent variable before evaluation so as to avoid any existing definition.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate. In particular, Mr. Wizard's answer recommends using `Evaluated -> True` instead of `Evaluate[funcs]`.