# Attempt to evaluate a series returning Indeterminate while running Plot

Tags: plotting, series-expansion

I have a function in the form of a Series from a prior calculation:

```
sol2D = SeriesData[a, 0, {Rational[3, 16] Pi, 
Rational[-5, 2], Rational[3, 4] Pi}, 0, 3, 2]
```

When I use Normal and substitute values for a, it works just fine:

```
Normal[sol2D] /. a -> 5.107142857142856`*^-6
```

gives

```
0.583411
```

I would like to Plot this function so I can compare it to my expected result.

```
Plot[{Normal[sol2D]}, {a, 0, 1}]
```

But when I try to plot it, I get an error message: "SeriesData::ssdn: Attempt to evaluate a series at the number 5.107142857142856`*^-6. Returning Indeterminate." and many similar errors.[image]

How do I plot my series without getting these errors?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Try: `Plot[Evaluate@Normal[sol2D], {a, 0, 1}]`

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Syed could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1731](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate) and perhaps many others.